# node-cron timing system for hours after 12 am

Tags: node.js, cron, schedule, node-cron

Quick question:

I know that this:

```
cron.schedule(`0 8 * * *`)
```

Sets the schedule for 8am.

What would it need to be for 8pm?

Comment: 16? The day has 24 Hours... https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron#allowed-values

Comment: It will be 20 as per 24 hours clock, refer: https://crontab.guru/#0_20_*_*_*